# Confusing: derivatives of a function w.r.t. each entry and each row vector of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

It is a basic matrix factorization problem. Suppose I have a matrix **Y** and it was factorized into low rank matrices **W** and **H** (rank is $d$, where $d$ <= $n$ ). The following is the noation:

$C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (it is a weight matrix),
$Y \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$,
$W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$,
$H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$,
$W_{k.}$ is the $i$th row of $W$ (row vector of $W$),

The following is the objective function:
$$f = \sum_{ij}C_{ij}(Y_{ij}- \sum_r W_{ir}H_{jr})^2$$

I would like to get the derivative of function $f$ with respect to each entry of $W$ (that is $W_{kl}$ (at this time $H$ is considered to be constant), that is:

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}}=? \quad (1)$$

and the derivative of function f with respect to a row vector of $W$ (that is $W_{k.}$) (at this time $H$ is considered to be constant), that is:
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial W_{k.}}=? \quad (2)$$

What is the trick to get such derivative including double summation notation?

By the way, I can get the derivative $\frac {\partial f}{\partial W}$ (that is with respect to whole matrix $W$) using the hadamard noation and frobenius norm by convert the objective function to the form $f=\|C \circ(Y-WH^T)\|_F^2$ (I learned it from @hans and other people, thanks!). However using this method, some close form solution expression is not easy to get or the computation for the inverse of the final matrix is costly or the kronecker product will generate a bigger matrix which is difficult to store into the memory. That is the reason why I would like to get the derivative of function $f$ with respect to a row vector instead of the whole matrix and iterate computation to all rows.

For the double summation notation $\sum_{ij}$, what is the trick to remove or reduct double summation to single summation $\sum_j$? Or write down double summation from $\sum_{ij}$ to $\sum_i \sum_j$? I checked the similar question asked here, but it is difficult for me to master the technique of solving such derivative, so I sincerely hope you can help me!

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should start by getting your notation unambiguous, this helps to avoid confusion. If you have a sum $\sum_{ij} A_{ij}B_{ji}$ it is good practise to not use $i,j$ when differentiating, cause these are already used for summation. Rather use $\frac{\partial}{A_{kl}}$ and make use of the fact that $\frac{\partial}{A_{kl}} A_{ij}=\delta_{ki}\delta_{lj}$ ($\delta$ being the Kronecker delta). In addition, make summation explicit, that is, instead of writing $A_{k.}B_{l.}^T$ write $\sum_m A_{km}B_{ml}$

Comment: Thanks @Thomas.  Can you give some details about the equation $(1)$ and $(2)$. For me, I lack of much skill for math, but I like it. I can learn from your answer. Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually I don't feel inclined to elaborate on this in detail, sorry. But to follow up on my first comment, as for (1), you are differentiating with respect to $W_{ik}$ which will end up in a mess unless you rename $i$ to something else either in the definition of $f$ or in the derivative. If you do that it's just a matter of discipline and standard rules (product rule) to get the derivative right. As for (2), you should make up your mind what the dot is actually supposed to mean and write it down explicitly, as soon as you do differentiation will become much easier.

Comment: @Thomas. Thanks. I have modified the notation according to your suggestion. I will try it.

Comment: You have calculated $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$. Now use the single-entry matrix $E_{kl}$ -- which has a 1 in the $k^{th}$ row and $l^{th}$ column and zeros elsewhere -- to calculate the component-wise derivative as $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}} = E_{kl}:\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$$where the colon denotes the Frobenius Inner Product.

Comment: If you want the derivative wrt the $k^{th}$ row or column of $W$ then pre-multiply or post-multiply the full matrix expression by the $k^{th}$ cartesian vector {$e_k$}, e.g. $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_k} = e^T_k\Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}\Big)$$

Comment: @lynn  Thanks so much. Can you provide me a reference for this kind of method (using Frobenius inner Product). It seems like that Frobenius inner product and hadamard product can solve any problem if approperately used, right? One more question is that the pre-calculation of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$ need large computation and memory if $m$ and $n$ are large. That is why I need a formula to compute just a row of $W$ each time and iterate all rows of it.

Comment: @lynn The result seems like this: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}} = \sum_j C_{kj} (\sum_r W_{kr} H_{jr} - Y_{kj})V_{jl}$   Can you simplify the frobenius result of yours and get this? Can you help check result? Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant $H_{jl}$ rather than $V_{jl}$ for the last term. Other than that it looks okay. If you are uncomfortable with the Frobenius product, you can express things in terms of cartesian base vectors $$\eqalign{E_{kl}:M &= e_ke_l^T:M \cr &= e_k^TMe_l}$$

Comment: @lynn. Thanks for your correct.  Here it is. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}} =2 \sum_j C_{kj} (\sum_r W_{kr} H_{jr} - Y_{kj})H_{jl}$. I really would like to learn from your method. I hope you can give me some references or course or books which is very helpful for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: @lynn. Hi Lynn, it is too difficult for me to follow your method. Can you write down the steps how to get the result: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}} = 2\sum_j C_{kj} (\sum_r W_{kr} H_{jr} - Y_{kj})H_{jl}$ using your method: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_{kl}} = E_{kl}:\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}$. Thanks so much.